# Problems with Program flow

Tags: c++

So I'm going to preface by saying this is my first post.  I've hit a bit of a rut and can't find a simple answer that's working for me.

I'm so new I'm still on command line programs but here I want to create a program that will accept an int value from the user.  I want to check and verify that it is in fact an integer value.  If it is not I want the user to be told to input a correct integer value.  If it is correct I want to move on.  I want to continue to ask for proper input until the user gives me an integer value.

Here's what I have been attempting to do:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

   int n;

   do {

      if (isdigit(n)==false) {
         cout<<"Enter an integer number\n";
         cin>>n;
         continue;
      }
      else {
         cout<<"Good Job\n";
      }
   } while(isdigit(n)==false);

}
```

As you can probably guess this gives me an infinite loop.  I cannot for the life of me get this to behave how I want it to.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212043/integer-input-validation-how and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16934183/integer-validation-for-input

Comment: @Zack if you check that `isdigit(n)` when `n` is an `int` .. would it ever fail and give false ??? :)

Comment: thanks jrd, that helps to point me more in the correct direction.  The whole process of variable validation is more difficult than I thought.

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track. The checks you are performing to determine an integer was successfully read is not correct. `isdigit` is meant to check whether a single character is a digit or not. The range of values for which `isdigit` returns `true` is [`'0'` - `'9'`]. Expressed in integers, that range is [48 - 57]. It is not a valid use for your purpose.

Here's an updated version that should work:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

   int n;
   while ( true )
   {
      cout << "Enter an integer number\n";
      if ( cin >> n )
      {
         cout<<"Good Job\n";
         break;
      }
      else
      {
         // Clear the stream and ignore the rest of the line.
         cin.clear();
         cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
      }
   } 
}
```

Comment: I still end up with an infinite loop if I enter a non-integer.

Comment: @Zack, good point. See the updated code about ignoring the rest of the line.

Comment: There should be `cin.clear();` before `cin.ignore(...)` otherwise the loop doesn't break upon wrong input. Or maybe this is a problem specific to MSVC!

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems here.

1. Firstly, as @jrd1 has linked, the way you cast `cin>>n` is incomplete. Your program's function appears to require some kind of validation, but `cin` fails if the input is not numeric (see the use of `cin.fail()` in [integer input validation, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212043/integer-input-validation-how) and [Integer validation for input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16934183/integer-validation-for-input)). You must check if `cin` has failed, and refresh `cin` for the next round of input.
2. One of your `if` statement and `while` statement is redundant, since `n` does not change between the evaluation of `while` and `if` on the subsequent loop.
3. Since you must check if `cin` has failed, there is no need to additionally check `isdigit(n)`. That is, if `cin` did not fail, then `n` must be a digit.
4. Your `continue` statement is redundant. `continue` skips to the end of the loop, but this is not necessary since all the remaining code is in the `else` block, hence there is nothing to skip over. This is only useful if you want to skip any code after your `if` block (which your code doesn't have).
5. Your intention with the `else` block appears to indicate a successful validation. You may consider using a `break` statement, which breaks the code execution out of the current loop.

Once you take into account of all of these, you will arrive at something like @R-Sahu's code.

This is an example that most closely resembles your code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int n;

    do {
        cout<<"Enter an integer number\n";
        cin>>n;

        if(cin.fail()) {
            cout << "Wrong Input" <<endl;
            cin.clear(); 
            cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 
        } else {
            break;
        }

    } while (true);

    cout<<"Good Job\n"<<endl;

}
```

Here is another example that is "more" streamlined, and does not require `break` or `continue` statements (stylistic choices for better "readable" code by some programmers)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int n;

    cout << "Enter an integer number\n" << endl;
    cin>>n;
    while ( cin.fail()){
            cout << "Wrong Input. Enter an integer number\n" <<endl;
            cin.clear(); 
            cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cin>>n;
    }

    cout<<"Good Job\n"<<endl;

}
```

EDIT: fixed a problem in the second example where `! cin>>n` was not behaving as expected.

EDIT2: fixed a problem in the first example where `isdigit` was incorrectly applied. See R Sahu's explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help guys, I was finally able to get the code to run using a slightly modified version of ch41rmn's suggestion.  The "streamlined" version directly bypassed the while loop.  And the second one didn't exit even if a correct int value was given.  This is what I used:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int n;

    do {
        cout<<"Enter an integer number\n";
        cin>>n;

        if(cin.fail()) {
            cout << "Wrong Input" <<endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
        else{
            break;
        }

    } while(isdigit(n)==false);

    cout<<"Good Job\n";

}
```

while this might be quite redundant, I'm happy the SOB runs.

THANKS!