# Beginner C++ input behviour

Tags: c++

This program is a very simple code in my practice to learn C++. The problem is at some point it does not accept input from `cin` and behaves strangely.
The code and the output of the program are below.

Why does the program not consider `cin` at "Enter your first name please"?

[image]

```
# include "cmath"
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string FirstName, MiddleName, LastName;
    string WelcomeMessage = "Welcome to Visual C++";
    int Number_of_Steps = 5;
    int LoopStart = 1, LoopEnd = 5;
    int AgeYears, AgeMonths;
    double Pi = 3.14;
    float k = 5.366;
    double Age;
    char* Symbol = "k"; 
    bool TestResult = true;

    MiddleName = "Milton";

    cout << "Input Your First Name and Last Name" << endl;
    cin >> FirstName >> LastName;
    cout << "Input your Age in Years" << endl; 
    cin >> AgeYears;
    cout << "Imput your Age in Months " << endl;
    cin >> AgeMonths;
    Age = AgeYears + AgeMonths / 12;
    cout << endl << "Your Name is " << FirstName << ' ' << LastName << endl;
    cout << "Your Age is " << Age << endl;
    cout << "The Character is " << Symbol << endl;

    // Testing operators
    cout << "Please Enter a floating point number \n";
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "n==" << n
        << "\n n+1==" << n + 1
        << "\n n three times==" << 3 * n
        << "\n n twice ==" << n + n
        << "\n nsquared ==" << n*n
        << "\n half of n ==" << n / 2
        << "\n square root of n ==" << sqrt(n)
        << "\n";    

    // Testing string addition
    cout << "Eneter your first name please" << endl;
    string String1, String2, String3;
    cin >> String1;
    cout << "Enter your family name please" << endl;
    cin >> String2;
    String3 = String1 + " " + String2;
    cout << "Welcome" << " " << String3 << endl;

    // testing inequalities to strings
    string FirstString, SecondString;
    cout << "Input First String "
        << endl;
    cin >> FirstString;
    cout << "Input Second String "
        << endl;
    cin >> SecondString;
    if (FirstString == SecondString)
        cout << "The two words are identical \n";
    if (FirstString >= SecondString)
        cout << "First word is bigger than second word \n";
    if (FirstString <= SecondString)
        cout << "Second word is bigger than first word \n";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get a hint from the output displaying `.2` as the first name (`String1`).  The `cin` operation before asking for first name had `64.2` on the buffer but because you read the value into an `int n` it only read the integer portion `64` and left the `.2` on the buffer.  Changing the declaration n to `float n` or doing some input validation if you did want an integer should leave the buffer empty when you get to the request for first name.

Comment: thanks Logan for your help - but could you please explain it further ?

Comment: When you say `int n; cin >> n;`, and `cin` contains `3.14`, it will only read the integer `3` from `cin`, and leave `.14` in `cin`. When you get to `cin >> String1;` it doesn't ask the user to enter anything because `cin` already contains a 'string': `.14` can be considered a string. So it writes `.14` to `String1` and continues.

Comment: Changing `n` to a `float` would fix it. Erasing the contents of `cin` before asking for input fix it too - [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/a/257182/2449857). Sorry, it's not a very elegant way

Comment: Stated another way, when `64.2` is entered, `cin` will read as much as it can to read in an `int` (n is declared `int` not `float` in your code).  The `6` and the `4` are valid for an `int` but It will stop when it reaches the `.` because `.` isn't part of an integer.

Comment: I got it - THANKS LOGAN

Comment: Great, happy C++ing

Comment: Quite Happy - I spent 1 hour trying to figure what is happening - cheers

Comment: Appreciated very much your help all - certainly Stack Overflow will be my Home Land in the upcoming next months

Comment: is there a way to show my appreciation - like : like on facebook ?

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, you can mark it as correct and it will put a green check mark by it.  This gives the answerer some reputation points and lets others know you have had your question adequately responded to.

Comment: May I ask also - how to validate the input for a specific type (using simple c++ statements ?)

Comment: Stackoverflow has a wealth of existing answers and you can search through them to find that, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16934374/5894196.  If after searching you don't find the answer you need, you can ask a new question but try to avoid asking duplicate questions.

Comment: Thanks Jack Deeth - sorry I missed your contribution yesterday - cheers